# Testing mailer/ contact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, mailer

I created a movie review website which allows a logged in user to add, edit and delete a movie as well as leave reviews for each movie. I have also implemented a mailer for my contact form that sends a 'fake email' (displayed on the console only).

This is my first time working with Ruby so I am unsure on how to test my controller and method for contacts. Any form of advice will be much appreciated.

contacts_controller.rb:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
def new
 @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
 @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
 @contact.request = request

 if @contact.deliver
   flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you  soon!'
  else
   flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
   render :new

  end
 end
end
```

contact.rb:

```
  class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

 # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
 # in ActionMailer accepts.
 def headers
  {
   :subject => "My Contact Form",
   :to => "your_email@example.org",
   :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
  }
  end
end
```

routes:

```
 contacts    GET    /contacts(.:format)     contacts#new    
             POST   /contacts(.:format)     contacts#create
 new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format) contacts#new
```

My testing so far:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ContactsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

test "should get contact" do
get :new
assert_response :success

 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more information here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers

```
require 'test_helper'

class ContactsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "ActionMailer is increased by 1" do
    assert_difference 'ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size', +1 do
       post contacts_url, params: { name: 'jack bites', email: 'bite@jack.org', message: 'sending message', nickname: 'jackbites' }
    end
  end

  test "Email is sent to correct address" do
    post contacts_url, params: { name: 'jack bites', email: 'bite@jack.org', message: 'sending message', nickname: 'jackbites' }
    invite_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
    assert_equal 'bite@jack.org', invite_email.to[0]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. Using that link, I have been trying to understand but I'm still unsure on how to apply those principles for my testing.

Comment: look to `10.3 Functional Testing` to test in your controller. Please let me know if you have question.

Comment: Based on 10.3 I have come up with the following test: 

    test "send email" do
       assert_difference 'ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size', +1 do
      post send_email_url, params: { email: 'info@mymovies.com' }
     end
    send_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
    end


Could you please guide me if I'm on the right track here as I am utterly confused.

Comment: I made you an example in my answer, please check modification answer above.